# У меня есть массив const char* и мне нужно пройтись циклом через указатели по этом массиве

Tags: c++, массивы, строки, указатели

Я знаю как можно проходится только так:

```
for (size_t index = 0; str[index] != '\0'; ++index)
{
    .....................   
}
```

Но препод сказал пройтись указателями. я все перерила и не нашла  норм материал чтобы разобратся. Нужна ваша помощь...

UPD:

```
   std::string st;
   for (const char* s = str; *s; ++s)
    {
        if (isspace(str[s])))
        {
            st += str[s];
        }
    }
```

Comment: `for(const char* s = str; *s; ++s){ ... }`

Comment: Не `str[s]`, а `*s`.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::string st;
...
for (const char* s = str; *s; ++s)
     if (isspace(*s)) st += *s;
```